# Can not update a boolean value in table by vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have a boolean field when I try to update from false to true for a single or multiple records it works but when trying to update it back to false it works for the first record only and can not repeat to update multiple records at the same time without refreshing the page 1- my vue component that handles the request is like this:

```
<template>
<div v-for="(channel, index) in items" :key="channel.id">
<a href="" @click.prevent="toggleVisibility(channel)">
<i v-if="channel.active" class="fas fa-stop default-stop" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Stop Channel"> 
</i>
<i v-else class="fas fa-play" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Start Channel"></i>
</a>
</div>
</template>

export default {
    name: "Channels",
    props: ['allChannels'],
    data() {
        return {
            items: this.allChannels
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleVisibility(channel) {
            axios[channel.active ? 'delete' : 'post'](`/visible-channels/${channel.name}`);
        }
    }
}
```

and my routes:

```
Route::post('/visible-channels/{channel}', 'ChannelsController@activate');
Route::delete('/visible-channels/{channel}', 'ChannelsController@deactivate');
```

my controller:

```
public function activate(Channel $channel, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->method() == 'POST') {
        $channel->update(['active' => true]);
    }
    return back();
}

public function deactivate(Channel $channel, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->method() == 'DELETE') {
        $channel->update(['active' => false]);
    }
}
```

The model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class Channel extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

protected $casts = [
    'active' => 'boolean',
];

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); 

    static::updating(function () {
        return Cache::forget('activeChannels');
    });
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just change in the boot function to wait until the update finish

```
 static::updated(function () {
    return Cache::forget('activeChannels');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since laravel stores boolean as `1` and `0` in database, You should probably set `active` property to `boolean` in your model

That's because laravel treat `false` as string so when you set `active` to false it compares it as `'false' == true` which is `true` so it stores `1` in database.

```php
class Channel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```